# How to decrypt encrypted application data in wireshark?

Tags: ssl, wireshark-dissector

I have some HTTPS/SSL packets between client and the server. I need to decrypt the application data after the SSL handshake. I have a SSL server key as well. I configured wireshark to take the private key like shown below.

I went to EDIT-> Preferences-> protocols->SSL -> Add private key to RSA key list. 
I have a JKS keystore configured on the server and I converted it to PKCS format and gave in wireshark. But still I am not able to decrypt the data . Please help

Comment: Which cipher suite are you using?

Comment: Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Or, see the Wireshark wiki and [Secure Socket Layer (SSL)](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

Comment: Anyway I resolved this by myself. Sorry if I posted it in wrong place.

Comment: nice solution you have here